# how to get information from ARM register when system crash

Tags: arm, stack-trace, trace

Pre-condition:

I use ARM11 processor, armcc-4.1 compiler, threadx OS, T32 for debugger

My target processor is ARM11 and sometimes after the system go to crash, the OS will provide some stack information, for some crash, it shows like:

```
 [20:44:54.6]  Trap Class: 0xAAAA (HW DATAABORT TRAP)
 [20:44:54.6]  System Stack: 
 [20:44:54.6]   0x600DB570
 [20:44:54.6]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.6]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.6]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.6]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.6]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.6]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.7]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.7]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.7]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.7]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.7]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.7]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.7]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.7]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.7]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.7]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.7]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.7]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.7]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.7]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.8]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.8]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.8]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.8]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.8]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.8]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.8]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.8]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.8]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.8]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.8]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.8]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.9]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.9]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.9]   0x00000000
 [20:44:54.9]   0x600DB8A0
 [20:44:54.9]   0x600CF2E8
 [20:44:54.9]   0xE5920004
 [20:44:54.9]   0x60013C20
 [20:44:54.9]   0x602FF288
 [20:44:54.9]   0x00100000
 [20:44:54.9]   0xE5920000
 [20:44:54.9]   0x405C2184
 [20:44:54.9]   0x405C2184
 [20:44:55.0]   0x405C2184
 [20:44:55.0]   0x00000000
 [20:44:55.0]   0x00000195
 [20:44:55.0]   0x60013C20
 [20:44:55.0]   0x00000001
 [20:44:55.0]   0x00000000
 [20:44:55.0]   0x405C218C
 [20:44:55.0]   0x00093400
 [20:44:55.0]   0x00093478
 [20:44:55.0]   0x00093400
 [20:44:55.0]   0x00093478
 [20:44:55.0]   0x60000000
 [20:44:55.0]   0x00088DEC
 [20:44:55.0]   0x0632EA00
 [20:44:55.1]   0x00000000
 [20:44:55.1]   0x04300001
 [20:44:55.1]   0x04300001
 [20:44:55.1]   0x32200221
 [20:44:55.1]   0x21111291
 [20:44:55.1]   0x00033F0F
 [20:44:55.1]   0x0000704B
 [20:44:55.1]   0x04300001
 [20:44:55.1]   0x04300000
 [20:44:55.1]   0xFFFFFFFF
 [20:44:55.1]   0x0000F103
 [20:44:55.1]   0x60000000
 [20:44:55.2]   0x00088DEC
 [20:44:55.2]   0x0632EA00
 [20:44:55.2]   0x00000001
 [20:44:55.2]   0x35840C01
 [20:44:55.2]   0x34040001
 [20:44:55.2]   0x11000091
 [20:44:55.2]   0x11001111
 [20:44:55.2]   0x00033F0F
 [20:44:55.2]   0x0000704B
 [20:44:55.2]   0x04300001
 [20:44:55.2]   0x04300000
 [20:44:55.2]   0xFFFFFFFF
 [20:44:55.2]   0x00001903
 [20:44:55.2]   0x40000000
 [20:44:55.3]   0x00084E60
 [20:44:55.3]   0x0632EA00
 [20:44:55.3]   0x00000000
 [20:44:55.3]   0x04300001
 [20:44:55.3]   0x04300001
 [20:44:55.3]   0x22200211
 [20:44:55.3]   0x22101211
 [20:44:55.3]   0x00000909
 [20:44:55.3]   0x04300001
 [20:44:55.3]   0x04300000
 [20:44:55.3]   0xFFFFFFFF
 [20:44:55.3]   0xFFFFFFFF
 [20:44:55.4]   0x00020909
 [20:44:55.4]   0x0000F917
 [20:44:55.4]   0x00000004
 [20:44:55.4]   0x40000000
 [20:44:55.4]   0x00084E60
 [20:44:55.4]   0x0632EA00
 [20:44:55.4]   0x00000001
 [20:44:55.4]   0x16040C01
 [20:44:55.4]   0x04302001
 [20:44:55.4]   0x21301191
 [20:44:55.4]   0x11001291
 [20:44:55.4]   0x000009C9
 [20:44:55.5]   0x04300001
 [20:44:55.5]   0x04300000
 [20:44:55.5]   0xFFFFFFFF
 [20:44:55.5]   0xFFFFFFFF
 [20:44:55.5]   0x00020909
 [20:44:55.5]   0x00005013
 [20:44:55.5]   0x00000004
 [20:44:55.5]   0xEA000049
 [20:44:55.5]   0xE3A00003
 [20:44:55.5]   0xE5C20005
 [20:44:55.5]   0xE5C30005
 [20:44:55.5]   0xE1A00006
 [20:44:55.5]   0xEBFFE638
 [20:44:55.5]   0xEA000043
 [20:44:55.6]   0xE5D20002
 [20:44:55.6]   0xE3100020
 [20:44:55.6]   0x0A000005
 [20:44:55.6]   0xE3A00009
 [20:44:55.6]   0xE5C20005
 [20:44:55.6]   0xE5C30005
 [20:44:55.6]   0xE1A00006
 [20:44:55.6]   0xEBFFE62F
 [20:44:55.6]   0xEA00003A
 [20:44:55.6]   0xE3A04016
 [20:44:55.6]   0xEA000038
 [20:44:55.6]   0xE3A04016
 [20:44:55.7]   0xEA000036
 [20:44:55.7]   0xE3A0400B
 [20:44:55.7]   0xEA000034
 [20:44:55.7]   0xE3550000
 [20:44:55.7]   0x0A000008
 [20:44:55.7]   0xE3550001
 [20:44:55.7]   0x0A000001
 [20:44:55.7]   0xE3550002
 [20:44:55.7]   0x1A00002D
 [20:44:55.7]   0xE5D20002
 [20:44:55.7]   0xE3100020
 [20:44:55.7]   0x1A000001
 [20:44:55.7]   0xE3A04016
 [20:44:55.7]   0xEA000029
 [20:44:55.8]   0xE351000B
 [20:44:55.8]   0x0A000007
 [20:44:55.8]   0xE3510003
 [20:44:55.8]   0x0A000005
 [20:44:55.8]   0xE351000A
 [20:44:55.8]   0x0A000003
 [20:44:55.8]   0xE3510009
 [20:44:55.8]   0x0A000001
 [20:44:55.8]   0xE3510005
 [20:44:55.8]   0x1A00001C
 [20:44:55.8]   0xE1A00006
 [20:44:55.8]   0xEBFFE60C
 [20:44:55.9]   0xE59F10A0
 [20:44:55.9]   0xE1D110BE
 [20:44:55.9]   0xE1500001
 [20:44:55.9]   0x2A000016
 [20:44:55.9]   0xE5D21005
 [20:44:55.9]   0xE3510005
 [20:44:55.9]   0x1A000001
 [20:44:55.9]   0xE3A0400D
 [20:44:55.9]   0xEA000014
 [20:44:55.9]   0xE3550000
 [20:44:55.9]   0x1A000001
 [20:44:55.9]   0xE3510003
 [20:44:56.0]   0x1A000007
 [20:44:56.0]   0xE3550001
 [20:44:56.0]   0x1A000001
 [20:44:56.0]   0xE3510009
 [20:44:56.0]   0x1A000003
 [20:44:56.0]   0xE3550002
 [20:44:56.0]   0x1A000004
 [20:44:56.0]   0xE351000A
 [20:44:56.0]   0x0A000002
 [20:44:56.0]   0xE3A0000B
 [20:44:56.0]   0xE5C20005
 [20:44:56.0]   0xE5C30005
 [20:44:56.1]   0xE1A00006
 [20:44:56.1]   0xEBFFE5F7
 [20:44:56.1]   0xEA000002
 [20:44:56.1]   0xE3A04004
 [20:44:56.1]   0xEA000000
 [20:44:56.1]   0xE3A04004
 [20:44:56.1]   0xE3570000
 [20:44:56.1]   0x0A000001
 [20:44:56.1]   0xE3A00001
 [20:44:56.1]   0xFBFFCC58
 [20:44:56.1]   0xE320F000
 [20:44:56.1]   0xE320F000
 [20:44:56.2]   0xE1A00004
 [20:44:56.2]   0xEAFFFF93
 [20:44:56.2]   0x00002851
 [20:44:56.2]   0x00002859
 [20:44:56.2]   0x0000286A
 [20:44:56.2]   0x0000286F
 [20:44:56.2]   0x6000089C
 [20:44:56.2]  Register:
 [20:44:56.2]  r0:  0xE5920004  r1:  0x60013C20  r2:  0x602FF288
 [20:44:56.2]  r3:  0x00100000  r4:  0xE5920000  r5:  0x405C2184
 [20:44:56.2]  r6:  0x405C2184  r7:  0x405C2184  r8:  0x00000000
 [20:44:56.2]  r9:  0x00000195  r10:  0x60013C20  r11:  0x00000001
 [20:44:56.3]  r12:  0x00000000  r13:  0xFFFE2300  r14:  0x06052402
 [20:44:56.3]  r15:  0x405C218C
 [20:44:56.3]  SPSR: 0xA0000053  DFAR:  0x00000000  DFSR: 0x00000406
```

How can I get some information from this? or can I know something from the register like R0 to R14? what exactly do these mean?

Comment: What (if any) operating system are you using?  What is your compiler?  Can you debug (either directly on the host device) or from a remote development host?  You absolutely need a debugger; we absolutely need to know your compiler and your target OS/target environment.  IMHO...

Comment: @paulsm4, I used armcc compiler, threadx OS and T32 for debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you can see (first line) that the crash was caused by a "data abort". The possible causes of data aborts are:

- alignment faults
- translation faults
- domain faults
- permission faults.

You can read more about it on [ARM's official manual](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0211k/I31997.html).

After that you'll see the contents of the system stack (each line is a memory location).

And at the bottom you'll find the content of each register:

```
 [20:44:56.2]  Register:
 [20:44:56.2]  r0:  0xE5920004  r1:  0x60013C20  r2:  0x602FF288
 [20:44:56.2]  r3:  0x00100000  r4:  0xE5920000  r5:  0x405C2184
 [20:44:56.2]  r6:  0x405C2184  r7:  0x405C2184  r8:  0x00000000
 [20:44:56.2]  r9:  0x00000195  r10:  0x60013C20  r11:  0x00000001
 [20:44:56.3]  r12:  0x00000000  r13:  0xFFFE2300  r14:  0x06052402
 [20:44:56.3]  r15:  0x405C218C
```

Notice that the values are in hexadecimal (hence the 0x at the beginning of each).

You can also run the program with GDB to follow the content of each register after each instruction.

Comment: does R15 means program STOP there and problem may be around that position? I can NOT run this program by GDB, is firmware should be run on target system and compiled by armcc

Comment: Yes R15 is the Program Counter at the moment of the crash. Keep in mind the crash probably happened a couple of instructions before that, since ARM uses pipeline and the PC points to a couple of instructions ahead of execution. Also, keep in mind that those might be relative values, since the OS might load the program in different memory locations.

Comment: how can I run it with GDB? need I cross-compile my target firmware with gcc? it may take huge effort to modify the code, any other suggestion?

Comment: You may try to run it with an ARM simulator and connect GDB to it.